# Is it expected my avatar to change today, without me changing any settings?

Tags: support

I am pretty sure yesterday my avatar was in light colors, while today
is black and white, definitely different image.

Haven't done any changes in my settings and the email is the same.

> Is this expected change?

The avatar is served from gravatar.com with name the
md5sum of the email in the settings and some additional arguments.

I am **not** asking how to change my avatar.

Comment: This is a problem with Gravatar. We don't know why it's happening, but [we'll be checking with them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284037/1438).

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks. I think the other question is about different problem, but the issue well could be in gravatar.

Comment: Similar questions in [meta.mathSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24916/where-did-my-avatar-go).